# Internet Explorer 7 clickable area links with no fixed width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I would like to know if there's a way to set the clickable area of links always strech to the to the parents container when parent container doesn't have a fixed width.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gYukv/

On Firefox the link strechs with the text and the

tag, on IE7 the clickable area of link remains small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution wold be to use CSS expressions:

```
#header-modulos-lista li { width: expression((document.getElementById('header-modulos-lista').offsetWidth - 6) + 'px'); }
```

Where 6 is the sum of the border width (box model bug).

Comment: This freezes my Internet Explorer.

Comment: I used jQuery instead. Thanks.

Comment: You have to make sure the sum of the lateral borders are right. Else,  you will male an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this :

```
 #header-modulos-lista a { background:#333;display:  block; color: #000; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; padding: 0 10px; text-decoration: none;zoom:1;position:relative;}
```

The difference is I added zoom:1; and position:relative;

If that does not work, you may need to add/ change your Doctype to something else like this:

```
<!doctype HTML>
```

Comment: Tried with doctype, even removed the xml from <html xml...> but didn't worked! =/